# MySQL query where you can't access relations through joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have following MySQL Tables:

```
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName          | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName           | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| username           | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And:

```
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trainee_id             | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date                   | date     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration               | time     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| educationDepartment    | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| completedtasks         | longtext | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have two conditions. I have a start and a end-date from my second table and I want the data from a specific user which I just can verify through the "username" of the first table. It looks like this: username is known > I will get the id (Foreign Key) of the user > now I can use this Foreign Key to get userspecific data from the second table. I started my MySQL query and it looks like this atm:

```
SELECT date, duration, educationDepartment, completedtasks FROM programm_completedtask WHERE date BETWEEN "2014-04-07" AND "2014-04-11";
```

But how can I make it now user specific ? IMPORTANT: I just want a MySQL query, php or something like that won't help me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limits the results to one particular user:

```
SELECT date, duration, educationDepartment, completedtasks 
FROM programm_completedtask 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-04-07' AND '2014-04-11'
AND trainee_id = (select id from users where username = 'XYZ');
```

Comment: That worked ! I tried almost exactly what you did xP I just didn't set the ( ) before and after the second select statement :D

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

`SELECT 
  table2.username, 
  table1.date, 
  table1.duration, 
  table1.educationDepartment, 
  table1.completedtasks 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.trainee_id 
WHERE 
  table1.date BETWEEN "2014-04-07" AND "2014-04-11" AND 
  table1.username = 'someuser';`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the result from both tables, you should use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.username, p.date, p.duration, p.educationDepartment, p.completedtasks 
FROM programm_completedtask AS p
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.trainee_id
WHERE date BETWEEN "2014-04-07" AND "2014-04-11"
AND u.username = "knownusername";
```